# Rails : Devise : make `reset password` use `confirmation resend` if user is unconfirmed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, confirmation-email

Given the user is either waiting for a `confirmation email` or has been given one, how can I ensure they do not use the `reset password` process and *force* them to go through the standard confirmation forms (using the *confirmation* email).

In my case the user must choose a username after confirmation and password reset annoyingly bypasses this.

Comment: how did you solve this issue? please answer here if you have a solution

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the :recoverable module in the User model since that is what enables the password reset.

You'll also want to remove the Forgot your password link in devise/sessions/new.html.erb if you haven't already customized that page.